# Gradle dependency from Maven local

Tags: android, gradle

I would like to add a maven dependency in my gradle, but what I did didn't work. In my project gradle I put the code below to give my local maven repository url

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "${System.env.HOME}/.m2/repository" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Then in my app gradle I tried to add my dependency with

```
compile 'my.package.name:lib:version'
```

But I got an error and I can't figure out what to do

```
Error:Could not find my.package.name:lib:version.
```

When I launch a maven clean install, I get the path

```
C:\Home\.m2\repository\my\package\name\lib\version\lib-version.pom
```

Does someone know what I'm missing or what to do ?

Comment: This most likely won't solve the issue, but you can use `mavenLocal()` instead.

Comment: Well, I thought it was exactly the same but it seems to be different from maven { url } since it's working now.
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

1. Add a dependency:

   ```
   dependencies {
     compile '<groupId>:<artifactId>:<version>'
   ...
   ```
2. Add `mavenLocal()` or path to repo:

   ```
   allprojects {
     repositories {
       mavenLocal()
       . . .
     }
   }
   ```

   -OR-

   ```
   allprojects {
     repositories {
       maven {
           url uri('/Users/home/.m2/repository')
       }
       . . .
     }
   }
   ```